# How can I use subdirectories with react router?

Tags: reactjs

I'm new to React and trying to understand routing, in particular how to work with subdirectories in the URL path.

Here is my **App.js** file

```
import React from "react"
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route } from "react-router-dom"    
import Home from "./Home"
import About from "./About"
import Contact from "./Contact"
import NavBar from "./NavBar"
import Employees from "./Employees"
import EmployeesCreate from "./EmployeesCreate" 
class App extends React.Component {
    render(){   
        return (
            <Router>
                <div>
                    <NavBar />
                    <Switch>
                        <Route exact path="/">
                            <Home />
                        </Route>
                        <Route path="/about">
                            <About />
                        </Route>
                        <Route path="/contact">
                            <Contact />
                        </Route>
                        <Route path="/employees">
                            <Employees />
                        </Route>
                        <Route path="/employees/Create">
                            <EmployeesCreate />
                        </Route>
                    </Switch>
                </div>
            </Router>
        )
    }
} 
export default App
```

I'm  having trouble with the **/employees/create** path. It is loading the **Employees** component instead of the **EmployeesCreate** component.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: try this `<Route exact  path="/employees"><Employees /> </Route>`

Comment: If your question was answered and you are happy by the answer, you should accept that answer as correct one, so it would have a green tick, or at least vote up. It is "currency" of  stackoverflow, in  which you pay for peoples help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Route` component does a substring match and so `/employees/create` gets matched by the `/employees` route. Pass the `exact` prop to the `Route` component to make sure it only gets rendered when there's an exact match.

From the [docs](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Route/exact-bool),

> `exact`: `bool`
>
> When true, will only match if the path matches the `location.pathname` exactly.

```
<Route exact path="/employees">
  <Employees />
</Route>
```